# I am trying to import the model Product from another app in my django project

Tags: django, python-3.x

This is my screenshot having the directory structure in it:

enter image description here

But while getting the Product model attribute and print it shows me the empty query set like .

Here is my Ecom/settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for Ecom project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'r*4jisk#c^4gl0-#x_x_sm%f9t-t4#n@j$ea_6sep@1&aobl-k'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
    'product',
    'search',
    'cart'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Ecom.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Ecom.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_my_proj"),
]

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_cdn","static_root")


MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_cdn","media_root")"""
Django settings for Ecom project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'r*4jisk#c^4gl0-#x_x_sm%f9t-t4#n@j$ea_6sep@1&aobl-k'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
    'product',
    'search',
    'cart'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Ecom.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Ecom.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_my_proj"),
]

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_cdn","static_root")


MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_cdn","media_root")
```

here is my product/models/Product model

```
from django.db import models


class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def featured(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)

    def active(self):
        return self.filter(featured=True,active=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=100.00)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Also when I import like from Ecom.product.models import product . its show me the following error:
    from Ecom.product.models import Product
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Ecom.product'

here is my directory structure:

```
Ecommerce
  Ecom
    ├── cart
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── Ecom
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── home
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── forms.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── product
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── utils.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── utils.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── search
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── static_my_proj
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── main.css
    │   └── img
    │       └── ecom.png
    └── templates
        ├── base.html
        ├── card.html
        ├── contact.html
        ├── index.html
        ├── login.html
        ├── navbar.html
        ├── productdetail.html
        ├── productfeatureddetail.html
        ├── productfeatured.html
        ├── product.html
        ├── register.html
        ├── searchform.html
        └── searchproduct.html
```

here is my search/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from product.models import Product  #here i get the red mark under product.models and Product
#from django.apps import apps
#Product=apps.get_model('product','Product')

class SearchProductView(ListView):
    template_name = "searchproduct.html"


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchProductView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print(query)
        context['query'] = query
        # SearchQuery.objects.create(query=query)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        method_dict = request.GET

        query = method_dict.get('q',None)  # method_dict['q']

        if query is not None:
            print(Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)) #here i get the empty query set but here i want the result according to query.
            return Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=query) #here i want to filter using query

        return Product.objects.none()
```

Comment: What's the problem? It seems to be finding the Product model fine.

Comment: yaa ,but I get the empty query set. I want to be the object in the queryset if it is in my database.

Comment: Are you sure the object is in your database? There doesn't seem to be any other errors. maybe try running the query in the Python shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using model managers instead of overriding querysets.

```
class ActiveProductsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(active=True)


class FeaturedProductsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(featured=True, active= True)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=100.00)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    active_products = ActiveProductsManager()
    featured_products = FeaturedProductsManager()
```

Then you can use them as follows:

```
Product.active_products.all()
Product.featured_products.all()
```